# Mongoose or MongoDB removing 24 hours from date?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I have to be doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what it is.  I currently have a date field in my application that has a value format of MMMM, D YYYY.

For this example, I am going to be using the date October 1, 2018.

In the application, the user selects October 1, 2018 which logs as

`October 1, 2018`

Later I convert this date into a savable date by using `var docDate = new Date($('#insuranceExpiration').val()).toISOString();` which logs as

`2018-10-01T04:00:00.000Z`

I then add this to an object stringify it and send it to the server where I log the date and shows as

`2018-10-01T04:00:00.000Z`

I then use Mongoose to save this date to MongoDB but when I go to see the saved date I show

`2018-09-30T04:00:00.000Z`

I cannot figure out for the life of me why I am seeing a date 24 hours in the past from the date I choose.  Below is the mongoose code to see if I am doing something wrong on that end.

```
app.post('/api/myDocuments/insuranceGeneral', function(req, res ) {

    console.log(req.body.expires);
    // prints 2018-10-01T04:00:00.000Z

    InsuranceGeneral.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.rsaConPortal.id
    }, {
        $set: {
            "documents.insurance.name": req.body.name,
            "documents.insurance.expires": req.body.expires,
            "documents.insurance.url": req.body.url,
            "documents.insurance.uploadDate": req.body.uploadDate
        }
    }, function(err, doc) {

       if (err) throw err;

        res.send('Success');

    });

});
```

Even if I use a standard javascript date object I can print this on the browswer log

`Mon Oct 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

This prints on the sever just before mongoose

`2018-10-01T04:00:00.000Z`

But this is the end result in mongodb

`2018-09-30T04:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Thank you for the two downvotes but no comment.  I obviously am clueless on what this problem is.  If you need more information I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you and your server in different timezone. And mongodb uses `GMT`. If you are not declaring time in your iso date, it is setting it's time as `00:00.000Z`. So for `GMT` this is one day earlier. Simply you should convert your date to `GMT`, you can use [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) or you can fix problem by subtraction offset from date like this:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;


var date = new Date(new Date($('#insuranceExpiration').val())) - offset).toISOString();
```

or with moment.js

```
var date = moment($('#insuranceExpiration').val()).tz('GMT').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: I could not get either of these to work.  For the first option you provided I am getting an error of `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value` and for the second I am getting the following error `Moment Timezone has no data for GMT.`

Comment: When I split your first option into two lines `var date = new Date($('#insuranceExpiration').val() - offset);` and `var new Date(date).toISOString();` I return `1969-12-31T20:00:00.000Z`

Comment: I edited first option, i missed one parentesis so it should be
`var date = new Date(new Date($('#insuranceExpiration').val())) - offset).toISOString();`

Comment: Thank you Efe.  This ended up being a code blunder on my end.  The code as I had it originally was working but was being saved to the incorrect location making it look as though it was saving the wrong information when it wasn't saving anything at all.